# I want to look at 2 date & time fields and compare that to now to return a status

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

We have locations that are open or closed for the day. I want to create a list that has a status column that says if that location is open or closed based on two other date and time fields.

Example 1: Location 1 will be closed 12/27/2021 11:00 AM and reopened 12/29/2021 8:00 AM.
Example 2: Location 2 will be closed 12/27/2021 8:00 AM and reopened 12/27/2021 10:00 AM.

It seems like I can get this to work when the date (or number of days) is larger than 1 (like in example 1), but I can't get this to work when the location is closed for just a couple of hours (like in example 2).

Here is the formula that I am using:

```
=IF(NOW()>Closed,IF(NOW()<Opened,"Closed","Open"),"Open")
```

Thank you for considering my question!

Comment: which version of SharePoint you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, please apply the following steps :

1. The **Status** column must be a **Calculated Column**
2. Apply the following formula : If the **current date** is either less than the **closed date** OR greater than the **opened date** then the status should be **OPENED**, else if it's between'em than it should be **CLOSED**

[image]

```
=If(OR(Closed>=NOW(),Opened<=NOW()),"Open","Closed")
```

I hope this helped you.

Cheers.